# Recalculate an average value

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

In my Java application I need to recalculate an average value based on the following data:

1. I know current avg value - `avgValue`
2. I know that `avgValue` is an average value for list of 12 values - `count`.

Based on this information how to recalculate avgValue when a new `value` is added to this list of previous 12 values. What is the new `avgValue` for list of 13 values - `count + 1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Current Sum = avgValue * 12
New sum = current Sum + New value
New average = New sum / 13
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make sure you don't overflow your data type then you will want to avoid computing the sum. I would suggest using:

```
New average = avgValue + ((New value - avgValue) / 13)
```

Comment: works faster, but my tests fail with a following error -  expected:<4.333333333333333> but was:<4.333333333333334>

Comment: @alexanoid That's numerical precision. You consider that a failure? Do you really think you are ever going to have 16 places of significant digits?