# Continuous calculation of the mean of values?

Tags: python, mean, calculation, continuous

I have a sequence of numbers coming into my application over a period of time, for example: `[10, 8, 11, 9, 10, 8, 8, 11, 9, 8, 10, 11]`

I know i can calculate the mean of those values with `statistics.mean(x)`, but this requires me to store all the value i am getting.

Now the question: is there a way to calulate the mean of all the values everytime i get a new value, without storing each value?

It should be like this:

New value: 10 -> Mean: 10

New value: 8  -> Mean: 9

New value: 11 -> Mean: 9,6

etc...

Edit: i probably could just sum all values and count how many values i got..

Comment: It's for Java but the algorithm is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904332/recalculate-an-average-value

Comment: you have right concept, sum and a count will always allow you to calculate the mean. When new value comes in add it to the sum and increase the count by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just keep the sum and the number of numbers so far

```
def init_running_average():
    int total = 0
    int count = 0

    def add_number(x):
        nonlocal total, count

        count += 1
        total += x

        return total/count
    return add_number

avg = init_running_average()
print(avg(10)) # 10
print(avg(8)) # 9
```